# Can 2 people use Windows 10 at the same time, play with a controller, work with keyboard and mouse

Tags: windows-10, mouse, gaming, game-controller, multiple-instances

I've got multiple monitors and a strong PC with 2 sets of keyboards and mice and a game controller. What I want to achieve is that I can work while my wife plays a game at the same time. She'd play on one screen and I can work on another. The problem is if I use my keyboard and mouse the game recognises it as the new main input device. Another problem can be that some games need to be the active window in order to work (I believe some other don't have to be, they can work in borderless window mode or some other).

My question is, is it possible to separate different input and run 2 separate instances of programs with their own input at the same time on Windows 10?

Comment: You likely have an OEM license and two users cannot use the computer at the same time.

Comment: Technically, this is supported just fine.  Windows is windows but as @harrymc  and John point out, Microsoft will not allow you to do this without HACKS (hint hint).  If you were to search the google for `hack windows 10 to support multi session`.. you might get what you are looking for but nobody here can help you with that.  There is only one code base and all windows products share it so the answer is always in there "somewhere"

Answer (score 0):

Windows does not have such user interface that allows multiple users
on one Windows client version. Microsoft only supports it on the (costlier)
Windows Server.

I know of one commercial product that supports this way of working
(called multiseat) :
[ASTER](https://www.ibik.ru/).

The program has a trial version, which I recommend trying first.
Its most basic version allows two users, but the more advanced
versions can do more:

[image]